# How to center align 2 UIViews inside a container (UIView), without placing them inside a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uiview, uistoryboard

Center align (horizontal and vertically) 2 UIViews inside a container (UIView), without placing them inside a UIView. 
I know it can be done by placing them inside a UIView or UIStackView.

But how can we do it directly ??

---INTERVIEW QUESTION---

REF : -- [Sample output](https://ibb.co/esOpDU)

Comment: Check this image @ https://ibb.co/dzYcF9

Comment: Add the image to the question and explain a bit more. Your question says 2 views while the image has 3.

Comment: 2 or 4 hardly matters. The question is how to vertically and horizontally center align them.

Comment: Check this, contains 2 views @@ https://ibb.co/esOpDU

Comment: Yes i gave you the answer for centering it without putting inside the container view, you have to put the other constraints yourself.

Comment: Your answer only specifies one View. If i add center constraint for 2 Views, it will overlap both of them. I need it one below the other.

Comment: I feel like you are hiding a lot of the real question. What will happen if the views are of different sizes? Is the question really for 2 views or 'n' views?

Comment: This is the complete question. Question specified only 2 views and it won't matter if the views are of different sizes, as we have to center align both the views together. So the center will be (height of both views + spacing)/2.

Comment: Are the heights know before hand?

Comment: Yes. Height of the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Everyone is making things complicated...**

The easiest solution :

- Add Center Horizontal constraint for all the view
- Add Top constraint for View2 wrt. View1.
- Add Center Vertical constraint to View1, with constant as -(Height of View1 + Height of View2 + spacing between them)/2.

Thanks  to the interviewer only .